# Get the first number from a string in flash as2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have an input field which requires a number to be entered.

I don't want the entry to start with a zero.

How would I check that the field has not been started with a zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substring to check the first character in the string

```
if (String(myString).substr(0,1) == '0') {
//this is not allowed
}
```

Comment: When I try to trace out the variable I get undefined var testString =_global.myProperty; trace(testString.substr(0,1)); Do you know why?

Comment: what do you get if you trace testString? without the substr?

Comment: the value of the field entered, in this case 100000

Comment: Make sure that the string is actually a string, not an integer, try trace (String(testString).substr(0,1));